# Upgrade to MVC 4, areas now can't find scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I recently upgraded a MVC 3 project to MVC 4.

In the app there are 3 areas. The areas use the same scripts as elsewhere.

Before the upgrade views in areas just used scripts from the Main Scripts folder ( /Scripts) but now I get a 404 (Not Found) because its looking here - /AREANAME/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js

Obviously I dont want to duplicate the scripts folder to all the areas folders so my question is how do I make the areas use the scripts in the main folder?

I reference the scripts like this in layout page

Comment: How are you referencing the scripts?  More than likely this is because Razor 2 is now application root aware, whereas Razor 1 was not.

Comment: Not using Razor, as the application was written a while ago it is all .aspx
I'm referencing like this - 

     <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: "../Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"    ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use relative addressing.  Instead, use the MVC supplied tools for this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")"></script>
```

Even better, use the bundling and minification supplied tools in MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mystere Man for the answer. For .aspx views it is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")%>"></script>
```